# Mongoose does not update values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a field's value in my MongoDB with mongoose. However, it does not update it correctly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Test.findById(987456, function(err, doc) {
    if (doc) {
        var map = doc.data;
        map['2019-07-07'] = {
            TAS: "111",
            TWS: "222",
            TSWD: "333"
        }
        doc.set('data', map)
        doc.save((err, doc1) => {
             if(err) console.log(err);
             else{
              console.log(doc1)
             }
       });
    }
})
```

This is my Schema

```
var test = new Schema({
    data: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {} },
})
var Test = mongoose.model('test', test);
```

The data prior to updating inside the `data` field is `{ '2019-06-06': { TWS: '4', TAS: '27', TSWD: '33' }`

The code does not throw any errors and `console.log(doc1)` inside the save callback prints the correct value `{ '2019-06-06': { TWS: '4', TAS: '27', TSWD: '33' },'2019-07-07': { TAS: '111', TWS: '222', TSWD: '333' }}`

However, when I check MongoDB Atlas, the value is not changed at all.

Comment: Did you solve you problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate):

```
let query = { id: 987456 }  // or whatever your id / _id is
let update = { data: { TAS: "111", TWS: "222", TSWD: "333" }}

Test.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, function(err, doc) {
   console.log(doc)
})
```